# Django testing error installing fixture- no such table

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-fixtures

Strange error after running "python manage.py test"

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture 
'/home/voxa/django/test_test/resume/fixtures/initial_data.json': Could not load 
resume.Person(pk=1): no such table: resume_person
```

But i've used the same fixtures with "python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json"

UPD:

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client

from resume.models import Person

class ResumeTest(TestCase):

    def test_model(self):
        bio = Person(first_name="Homer", last_name="Simpson", birth_date="04.02.1978", email="mail@gmail.com", jabber="jabber@jabbim.com", skype="skype", other_contacts="tel: +380975322155", bio="Was born...")

    def test_index(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "Volodymyr")
```

Comment: Could you post your tests.py?

Comment: done, tests.py added

Comment: are you using migrations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using migrations, your initial_data.json is loaded [after every migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures). If you want to load a fixture in your tests, do this:

```
class ResumeTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['my_data']
    ...
```

See [Official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading).

Additionally, rename your 'initial_data.json' to 'my_data.json' to avoid it being loaded after every migration, which is what is probably causing your tests to fail.

Comment: nothing changed after adding this line. As we can see django can see fixtures, but cant download it in some reasons   "Problem installing fixture'/home/voxa/django/test_test/resume/fixtures/initial_data.json'"

Comment: Change the name of the file of that fixture to something else, like mydata.json.